# AFNetworking get responseObject in failure block

Tags: json, afnetworking

I am `GET` a json data from server, but the json data has a line break "\n", so i got the error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unescaped control character around
>   character 2333.) UserInfo=0x7fa054a02ab0 {NSDebugDescription=Unescaped
>   control character around character 2333.}

So i want to find where's the broken json data, escape it first and then parse it. But i can't find where the response data is.

Any help?

**Edited**:

```
            if let d = error.userInfo  {
                    println(d)
         println(d[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey])
                }
```

I tried this in failure block, `d[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] prints nil`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the response data from the NSError of the failure block:

```
NSData *errorData = [error.userInfo objectForKey:AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey];
```

From that, you may transform it to NSString or anything else you need to escape it and process it appropriately.